# Storing static and common data in React Native

Tags: javascript, json, database, react-native, realm

Hello I am creating a dictionary app in React Native and I simply want to store an array of JSON blobs that would hold the definitions of each word.

I would very much like to avoid having to hardcode the data and want my code to be DRY!

Sample JSON blob:

```
[
  {
    "word": "triangle",
    "definition": "a plane figure with three straight sides and three angles.",
    "type": "noun"
  },
  {
    "word": "square",
    "definition": "a plane figure with four equal straight sides and four right angles.",
    "type": "noun"
  },
  {
    "word": "circle",
    "definition": "a round plane figure whose boundary (the circumference) consists of points equidistant from a fixed point (the center).",
    "type": "noun"
  }
]
```

What is the best strategy to store this data so that it is:

1. Can be bookmarked by the user
2. Clean and easy to change and separated from other files
3. How it can be accessed by my React components

I think Relational DataBases are the best approach but I have difficulty figuring out how I would seed the database with data. And which library on React Native to use for a Relation Database.

Thank you for reading my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you are describing using Realm with the following schema:

```
let EntrySchema = {
    name: 'Entry',
    primaryKey: 'word',
    properties: {
        word: 'string',
        definition: 'string',
        type: 'string'
    }
};
let BookmarkListsSchema = {
    name: 'BookmarkList',
    properties: {
        bookmarks: {type: 'list', objectType: 'Entry'}
    }
};

let realm = new Realm({schema: [EntrySchema, BookmarkListsSchema]});
```

You can pre-populate a Realm file with all of your dictionary entries and bundle it with your app, or alternatively you could download this file or JSON and initialize your db when starting the app.

To create/add bookmarks:

```
// create your list once
var bookmarkList;
realm.write(() => {
    bookmarkList = realm.create('BookmarkList');
});

// add entry for 'triange' to bookmarks
realm.write(() => {
    let triangeEntry = realm.objectForPrimaryKey('Entry', 'triangle');
    bookmarkList.bookmarks.push(triangleEntry);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Ari. Can I prepopulate a Realm file with a normal js script? For example I would require the Realm library in a JS file and once I run that, would it output a Realm file?

Comment: If you run on the simulator you can prepulate the file in your RN app and easily copy out the file. You can figure out the path to the generated realm file with: `console.log(realm.path)`

Comment: Oh sweet! Thanks again!